# How to display values from two Mysql tables with similar columns.

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Good day, I selected two MySQL tables- tcomment and members, but these two tables have similar fields called 'id' and now, I want to select the id of the 'tcomment' table but instead, the id of 'members' table shows up. How do I do this? This is the code below.

```
<?php

              $comment= "SELECT c.*, m.* FROM tcomment c JOIN members m ON c.poster = m.id WHERE comment_id = :id";   

foreach ($db->query($comment, array('id' => $_GET['id'])) AS $tresult){

             echo  "{$tresult['id']}";
    }

?>
```

Comment: Thank you very much. It was useful. Got to learn more about fields aliases.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [**aliases**](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_alias.asp) on the SQL query;

**Sample Code**

```
 $comment= "SELECT c.*, c.id as comment_id, m.*, m.id as member_id FROM tcomment c JOIN members m ON c.poster = m.id WHERE comment_id = :id";
```

Answer (score 0):

As @u_mulder said, apply aliases

```
$comment =<<<ccc
    SELECT c.id AS 'idWanted', c.*, m.*
    FROM tcomment c JOIN members m ON c.poster = m.id
    WHERE comment_id = :id
ccc;

foreach ($db->query($comment, array('id' => $_GET['id'])) AS $tresult){

         echo  "{$tresult['idWanted']}";
}
```